# What is considered a "decoupled project" (Gradle)?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Hello everyone I am making a Cocos2d-x game which includes gradle files I was looking for ways to improve my build time and I tried googling and even looking at Gradle docs but I just can't seem to understand what exactly a "decoupled" project is ? In my `gradle.properties` it states this

```
# When configured, Gradle will run in incubating parallel mode.
# This option should only be used with decoupled projects. More details, visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:decoupled_projects
#org.gradle.parallel=true
```

for people who are not familiar with Cocos2d-x in the Gradle Scripts folder in Android Studio Cocos2d-x project it has 3 build.gradle files:

- (Project: proj.android)
- (Module: MyGame)
- (Module: libcocos2dx)

followed by `gradle-wrapper.properties`, `proguard-rules.pro(MyGame)`, `proguard-rules.pro(libcocos2dx)`, `gradle.properties`, `settings.gradle` & `local.properties`

with all this being said is my project considered a decoupled project ? and would uncommenting `org.gradle.parallel=true` improve build time or what exactly different would I notice ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check list of projects for an app by running following command.

```
gradlew -q projects
```

It's output will be like this

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Root project
------------------------------------------------------------

Root project 'MyApplication'
+--- Project ':app'
\--- Project ':mylibrary'
```

As per the [gradle link](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:decoupled_projects)

> Two projects are said to be decoupled if they do not directly access each other’s project model. Decoupled projects may only interact in terms of declared dependencies: project dependencies and/or task dependencies. Any other form of project interaction (i.e. by modifying another project object or by reading a value from another project object) causes the projects to be coupled.

If app is using dependency like

```
dependencies {

    implementation project(":mylibrary")
}
```

Then it is decoupled.